# I'm getting a white box surrounding Google One Tap

Tags: javascript, html, google-one-tap

I'm getting a white box surrounding Google One Tap:

[image: example of issue]

The code is this:

```
this.init = function () {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            auto_select: false,
            callback: cw.handleCredentialResponse,
            cancel_on_tap_outside: false,
        });

        google.accounts.id.prompt();
    }
```

I was expecting the same, but without the white box.

Comment: I would wager that part of the issue is your css affecting the box - have you tried inspecting the element with developer tools in your browser?

Comment: @JoSSte Yep, but I'm using tailwind, I dont have any personalized css sheet.

Comment: and you are sure that the google  box doesn't have a class/id that conflicts with one in your project?

Comment: @JoSSte Yes, they are no conflicts, because of the strange class names of google one tap